# Инвертировать движение камеры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При движении мышки или пальца в право камера движется влево. По Y аналогично. 
Как инвертировать движение?

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        touch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 direction = touch - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Camera.main.transform.position += direction;
    }
```

Comment: сделайте 
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - touch , а не наоборот

Comment: @Andrey Попробовал. Камера резко улетает в бесконечность  transform.position assign attempt for 'Main Camera' is not valid. Input position is { Infinity, -21034854041031541462711255394443853824.000000, -10.000000 }.
UnityEngine.Transform:set_position(Vector3)

Comment: смотрите что у вас происходит. Вы каждый кадр пока зажимаете кнопку прибавляете к позиции  камеры новое значение. Грубо говоря Кадр1(1 + 5), Кадр2(6+5) и так далее. И за секунду  она у вас улетит непонятно куда

Comment: @Andrey touch - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); при таком векторе все движется корректно, не считая того, что движение инвертировано. Суммируется ведь только пока есть движение, иначе direction 0.

Comment: ваше движение происходит не в ту сторону потому что вы не правильно высчитываете направление. Если вы хотите направление от touch к точке от камеры  то нужно так как я написал.А в вашем случае вы берете направление о точки камеры к touch

Comment: и уже после этого развивать идею с движением дальше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил вот так:

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        lastPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))      
    {
        Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - lastPosition;
        Camera.main.transform.position += dir * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
        Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(camPos.x, -limitX, limitX), Mathf.Clamp(camPos.y, -limitY, limitY), camPos.z);
        lastPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я немного модифицировал ваш код.  В direction вы получаете именно направление в которое должен двигаться какой-то объект с определенной скоростью

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            touch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) -  touch;
            transform.position += direction.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но появились новые проблемы. Движения начального варианта были четкие и быстрые. Здесь двигается некорректно. Например, не получается сменить движение резко в противоположную сторону и всё очень плавно. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь - буду думать дальше.